# Clean thermal paste from touch contact points on the underside of the CPU

Tags: cpu, cleaning, intel-core2, thermal-paste

I bought an used CPU (Intel "Core 2" E4700) on eBay and it came with the underside dirty with something that seems it´s thermal paste.

Before I send it back, I wonder if it could it still work without cleaning this dirt because the seller supposedly "tested" it to be fully working.

Final, is there a way to clean this dirt without damaging the CPU? Or, is it too risky (or too much work) to do so?

This is the CPU:

[image: Dirty CPU]

Comment: -1 Your terminology is bad. Include a photo

Comment: How about a suggestion _before_ giving a -1? I´m going to include a screenshot

Comment: I agree that a bit of rubbing alcohol on a cloth that won't leave bits of paper or fabric behind should work fine.  Just make sure it's dry before reinstalling!:-)

Comment: @RyanGriggs can I use a microfiber cloth, what type?

Comment: Not sure about microfiber, never used it - if abrasive then don't use it.   I agree with @mud - take antistatic precautions.  A paper napkin might work if it doesn't leave bits behind. Thats what I usually use on the heat spreader side when removing thermal paste.  Be very gentle -  don't want to damage the pads!

Comment: You probably don't have to worry about the thermal paste on the small discrete components in the middle - it should be non-conductive, and they won't touch anything. Just the pads to avoid gumming up the lga socket and/or bad connection.  I don't like q-tips for this type of work due to leaving threads of cotton behind.

Comment: @RyanGriggs What do you think about using this instead of alcohol? http://amzn.to/1jKZPyU

Comment: My personal opinion is that this is way overkill vs a $1 bottle of rubbing alcohol for this tiny bit of thermal paste, but that's up to you.  Also fwiw this doesn't say it's for connector pads but instead for the thermal surface.

Comment: The issue is that high purity alcohol is really difficult to find here (almost impossible personally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cleaning is definitely possible, I would take strict anti static procedures to ensure not damaging the CPU however. A clean soft sponge and a tiny bit of alcohol should be all you need, don't scrub hard or you could damage the sensitive contacts. I would contact the seller before performing this to see if they will replace it first or if they will replace if it doesn't work after cleaning.

Comment: What do you think about using this http://amzn.to/1jKZPyU instead of alcohol?

Comment: I've never used it simply because alcohol is very useful for cleaning many things so i always have it on hand and you can get a large bottle for very little money.

Comment: The issue is that high purity alcohol is really difficult to find here (almost impossible personally) –

Comment: You don't need extremely pure alcohols, the normal isopropyl alcohol from a big box retailer works fine, usually 80 to 90% alcohol by volume, check by the pharmacy. If you cannot get it at all, clean purified water will work but will require more GENTLE scrubbing than alcohol. Don't pour the water on and give the chip extra time to ensure it is totally dry.

Answer (score 3):

Nice picture, it does look like thermal paste slopped all over in places where it would effect the connections, and mess-up the sockets own tiny little connection points if applied without cleaning.

I would not blame you if you did send it back, but so far I  do not see anything that I have not done myself :-)  From being sloppy and getting fingers all over it.  It can be easily cleaned up.  tech spray, 91-99% isoprople alcohol , and sometimes a clean brush can help to wisk that stuff away.

[What's the proper way to remove thermal paste from a CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/132031/whats-the-proper-way-to-remove-thermal-paste-from-a-cpu?rq=1)

I have even run one of these under the sink with dawn (dishwashing liquid original only) and water :-) Then followed up with a proper alcohol flush and complete drying.

Sure it isn't good at all, to have been sent to you like this, but cleaning it is easy, and if it works , that is what counts.

Comment: Can I use this? http://amzn.to/1jKZPyU

Comment: yes, I have never found any need to do so, but it is formulated for just that.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this some problem and made a YouTube video on how to clean the contacts of a CPU. I recently bought two Xeon CPUs off of eBay and the thermal paste got onto contact pads. In the video I used 91% isopropyl alcohol and cotton swaps to clean both the underside and top side. At the end I show as a proof of concept that the CPUs still work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhyMdkOUtV4

Comment: I added more information to the answer. Also, the video directly answers the person's question.

Answer (score 0):

For contact cleaning use a matchstick (the non functioning end) dipped in Isopropyl alcohol or methylated spirit. Cloths, sponges and brushes risk leaving debris, a matchstick gives good scrubbing capability for stubbon elements without much risk of leaving debris.